# HTML parsing table in python using beautifulsoup in row-wise manner

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the table with electoral outcomes from [here](http://www.krasnodar.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/region/krasnodar?action=show&tvd=2232000821586&vrn=2232000821581&region=23&global=&sub_region=23&prver=2&pronetvd=1&vibid=2232000821616&type=381).
Basically, I'm interested in the results from
[this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj9aL.png).
I found many examples of parsing an html table, but in all of them the data of interest os organized in column-wise manner. However, my goal is to extract the data from rows (for example, I want to get the first row which is the name of electoral area etc, the second row, which is the number of registered voters etc). Currently, I am able to extract the first column:

```
sub_url = "http://www.krasnodar.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/region/krasnodar?action=show&tvd=2232000821586&vrn=2232000821581&region=23&global=&sub_region=23&prver=2&pronetvd=1&vibid=2232000821616&type=381"
page = urlopen(sub_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
table = soup.find("table", style = "width:100%;overflow:scroll")

for row in table.find_all("tr"):
cells = row.find_all("td")
if len(cells) == 42:
    first_column = cells[0]
    print first_column
```

The structure of html does not allow to simply change "tr" and "td". How can I extract the data in row-wise manner?

PS. I want something like 
`uiks = [УИК 101, УИК 102, УИК 103, ...]`

Answer (score 0):

You already are getting the results row-wise.
Please note: The code behind the `for row in...` has to be indented.

What about

```
rows = list()
for x, row in enumerate(table.find_all("tr")):
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    if len(cells) == 42:
        rows[x] = cells
        print rows[x]
```

Or you might want to create a nested dict containing the entries, using the "uiks" as first order keys. This depends heavily on your use case.

Comment: Probably, I was not precise enough. I added an updated picture of table, where I denote the way I want to get the data

Comment: It writes:
`File "<ipython-input-23-7334992f10b0>", line 5, in <module>
    rows[x] = cells

IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Answer (score 0):

You want to print only the first row of the table, so you must iterate all cells and stop after first line. But want you want is the text of first child node because the `<td`> content is like `<td align="center" style="color:black"><nobr>УИК №101</nobr></td>`.

So a possible code would be:

```
for row in table.find_all("tr"):
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    if len(cells) == 42:
        for cell in cells: # iterate all td cells
            print cell.findChild().txt,    # print all in same line
        print ''                           # only one newline
        break                              # only first row
```

Comment: Actually, I want not only the first row. Also I need the second, the 8th an 9th. What I want is to assign rows to lists and then create a dataframe